# Angular cli lazy loading doesn't work

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-cli

I every body, I try to use lazy loading in my angular 2 app generated by angular cli: the router works but no additional chunk file are generated.

this is my AppModule:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { APP_ROUTES } from "./app.routing";
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

//ng2 bootstrap
import { Ng2BootstrapModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { VotesModule } from './votes/votes.module';
import { InsertComponent } from './insert/insert.component';
import { VotesComponent } from './votes/votes.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    VotesComponent,
    InsertComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    Ng2BootstrapModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES),
    VotesModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

my app.routing:

```
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";

import { InsertComponent } from "./insert/insert.component";
import { VotesComponent } from "./votes/votes.component";

export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/vote', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'vote', component: VotesComponent },
    { path: 'auth', component: InsertComponent, loadChildren: 'app/insert/insert.module#InsertModule'}
];
```

the InsertModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { INSERTVOTES_ROUTES } from './insert-vote.routing';

import { InsertListComponent } from './insert-list/insert-list.component';
import { InsertVotersComponent } from './insert-voters/insert-voters.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(INSERTVOTES_ROUTES)
  ],
  declarations: [ InsertListComponent, InsertVotersComponent]
})
export class InsertModule { }
```

and the insert-vote.routing:

```
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";

import { InsertVotersComponent } from "./insert-voters/insert-voters.component";
import { InsertListComponent } from "./insert-list/insert-list.component";

export const INSERTVOTES_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'insert', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'insert', component: InsertVotersComponent },
    { path: 'voters', component: InsertListComponent }
];
```

[image: this is the screenshot in wich there isn't chunk file]

Is there some other dependecies I should install? Or any Idea?
Here there is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "votes",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.3",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.3.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.2.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.7.2",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^1.0.3",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.16",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.2",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.22-1",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your AppModule should have a route that loads your InsertModule via `loadChildren`. That's how the CLI can generate a separate bundle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update APP_ROUTES by removing component from lazy loaded route

```
 { path: 'auth', loadChildren:'app/insert/insert.module#InsertModule'}
```

And update your insert-vote.routing

```
{ path: '', component: InsertComponent },
{ path: 'insert', component: InsertVotersComponent },
{ path: 'voters', component: InsertListComponent }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove " InsertComponent" from declarations in the AppModule 
And remove "component: InsertComponent" from "APP_ROUTES" , I suggest you take a look at [Lazy-Loading route configuration](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)